# Why is there billowing dust in nebulae?

Tags: star, nebula

Why do some nebulae look like the billowing clouds? Wouldn't that require something like a viscosity in empty space?

Answer (score 3):

This is a very complex answer. It has to do a lot with gravity and electromagnetism. Nebulae are made of particles that act according to those forces and give you the illusion of viscosity. Those particles are actually moving. Take a look at this simulation it might give you an idea: [Simulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbdwTwB8jtc)